# Show a sequence generated value in success message upon form submission for Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form in Oracle APEX for entering a short report.  The Primary Key is generated by a sequence upon form submission. How might I go about displaying that primary key (report_ID) to the user in a form submission success message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two ways to show success message after process: first - in section `Messages` of process properties put desired message into `Process Success Message`, second - in process code execute following:

```
begin
  apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'your message here';
end;
```

`apex_application.g_print_success_message` is a variable of standard APEX package `apex_application`. In your case it is easier to add this line of code to calculating ID process.

**UPD**
Example of standard "Get PK" process with message generation:

```
begin 
    if :P12_ID is null then
        select "MY_SEQ".nextval
          into :P12_ID
          from sys.dual;
    end if;
  apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'new ID is ' || :P12_ID;
end;
```

Comment: I'm able to use the second method to update the success message, but I can't get the newly generated key value to show up. What's the trick to get it into the message?